# jquery, how to retrieve a set of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var $ds=$('.stars-wrapper1').each(function(i) {

     alert($(this).find(':first').attr('title'));
 });
```

I wan to get the attribute of each first child from each stars-wrapper1 class, in my code.

Here is how it looks:

```
        <div class="stars-wrapper1">
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="1" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="2" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="3" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="5" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="6" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="7" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="8" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="9" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="10" title="<?php echo $commentID;?>" />

        </div>
```

I want to get the title.. 
But all I get is an empty value in the alert. Note: I have several classes named stars-wrapper1..so I have to iterate over them and get the first attribute of the first child..something which I fail to do! :(

**UPDATE:
What the page sees:**

```
     Rating: <span class="stars-cap"></span>
        <div class="stars-wrapper1">
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="1" title="23"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="2" title="23"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="3" title="23" />

            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="23"  />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="5" title="23" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="6" title="23" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="7" title="23" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="8" title="23" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="9" title="23" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="10" title="23" />

        </div>
```

Comment: What you have looks like it should work... are you sure your PHP `echo` is actually echoing a value? http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/aK5P6/

Comment: Could you show us the markup the browser sees, not the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working. check [this on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/LahSa/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".stars-wrapper1 :first-child").each(function() { 
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

You don't need to iterate over all the stars-wrapper1-elements. Just use the :first-child selector to fetch the first child of each of them, and iterate over those.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kNuCw/1/ - Updated with my code snippet. Everything seems to work, though there's no php-generated code, obviously.

Comment: @alessioalex: you've forgotten to include the javascript :)

Comment: $('.stars-wrapper1:first-child').each(function(i) {
 
   alert($(this).attr('title'));
   
  
  });  for me it doesnt work.. But may be it is because I generate the jquery before the php is generated..therefore I see nothing

Comment: That's impossibru - When you receive the page from the server, the PHP is already run, generated and stripped. What's with the `i` in function(i)? How do you call the method?

Answer (score -2):

Try this
var $ds=$('.stars-wrapper1 input').each(function(i) {

```
 alert($(this).find(':first').attr('title'));
```

});